# How to use composes with non-CSS files in Vue Loader

Tags: vue.js, css-modules, vue-loader

Is there any way in Vue Loader to use `composes` with non-CSS files like Sass, Stylus, Less, etc?

```html
<style lang="stylus" module>
    .foo
        composes bar from './assets/css/base.styl'
</style>
```

At the moment it only works with plain CSS files.

Comment: What's version of vue loader and how is it configured (regarding CSS)?

Comment: Vue Loader 13.7.3. Included within [Vue.js Webpack Boilerplate 1.3.1](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/1.3.1) created with vue-cli 2.9.6. Vue Loader configuration is set [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/1.3.1/template/build/vue-loader.conf.js). I just tweaked that config a little bit to support [postcss-icss-values](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-icss-values). So my config file looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/srus/ad42b5ff82e09100cfc6662c7b63f46f).